# Scroll view is not scrolling content vertically with AutoLayout in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout

I have this `UIViewController` subclass:

```
class MyCustomViewController: UIViewController, MyDelegate {

   var scrollContainerView: UIView = {
      let scrollContainerView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
      scrollContainerView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      return scrollContainerView
   }()

   var scrollView: UIScrollView = {
      var scrollView = UIScrollView()
      scrollView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      return scrollView
   }()

   lazy var customView: MyCustomView = {
      var customView = MyCustomView(frame: .zero)
      customView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
      customView.delegate = self
      return customView
   }()

   override func loadView() {
      self.view = UIView()
      self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

      self.view.addSubview(self.scrollView)
      self.scrollView.addSubview(self.scrollContainerView)
      self.scrollContainerView.addSubview(self.customView)

      view.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
   }

   override func updateViewConstraints() {

        self.scrollView.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: self.view, withOffset: 0)
        self.scrollView.autoPinEdge(.Left, toEdge: .Left, ofView: self.view, withOffset: 0)
        self.scrollView.autoPinEdge(.Right, toEdge: .Right, ofView: self.view, withOffset: 0)
        self.scrollView.autoPinEdge(.Bottom, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: self.view, withOffset: 0)

        self.scrollContainerView.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: self.scrollView, withOffset: 0)
        self.scrollContainerView.autoPinEdge(.Left, toEdge: .Left, ofView: self.scrollView, withOffset: 0)
        self.scrollContainerView.autoPinEdge(.Right, toEdge: .Right, ofView: self.scrollView, withOffset: 0)
        self.scrollContainerView.autoPinEdge(.Bottom, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: self.scrollView, withOffset: 0)

        self.customView.autoPinEdge(.Top, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: self.scrollContainerView, withOffset: 0)
        self.customView.autoPinEdge(.Left, toEdge: .Left, ofView: self.scrollContainerView, withOffset: 0)
        self.customView.autoPinEdge(.Right, toEdge: .Right, ofView: self.scrollContainerView, withOffset: 0)
        self.customView.autoPinEdge(.Bottom, toEdge: .Bottom, ofView: self.scrollContainerView, withOffset: 0)

       super.updateViewConstraints()
   }
}
```

Where `customView` has fixed size. If I run the app in the iPhone 4S simulator, where it is supposed to be needed to scroll to see the complete view, I find that it scrolls horizontally, but not vertically... I don't understand what could I be missing.

Comment: You also need to add self.scrollContainerView constraint to self.view also.

Comment: @ArunGupta that it doesnt work for me...

Answer (score 1):

**It seems that there are two issues in your constraints,**

> 1. Set scrollContainerView EqualWidth to scrollView as you want your scroll view to be scroll vertically only.
> 2. If the customView does not have subViews inside it, it could not able to calculate the height required for it, so you either need to set
>      some points of FixedHeight to the customView or add subviews with top to bottom
>      constraints.

Everything else is fine.

Hope this would help you.

Comment: This "add subviews with top to bottom constraints" solved my issues. I've done this many times before and somehow forgot it  and this helped!